# check multiple condition with like statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I check two columns if the string "done" or "completed" is available in either of these columns.at this moment I write

```
case when col1 like '%done%' 
or col1 like "%completed%' 
or col2 like "%done%' 
or col2 like "%completed%' 
end as status
```

this is a sample so it's only 4 lines however if there are multiple strings that need to check it takes a lot of effort to write code like this. Can we write which gives a similar result?

```
(col1||"-"||col2) like (%done%,%completed%)
```

i know above code is not possible, but do we have any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lengthy list, create a table with one column and insert a row for each key word. Then write your query to join to this table using the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
  FROM maintable m,
       keyword_table k
 WHERE m.col1 LIKE '%'||k.keyword||'%'
```

Just be aware that this will not perform well in bulk (millions of rows). That would require more advanced techniques, but for small tables this is fine.

Comment: I can't create the table. There are several conditions like it and creating a table for each one is not feasible.

Comment: Not for each one... you create a single table, and you can insert a hundred, or a thousand, or whatever many %done% %completed%, etc... search strings as you want.